# Issue with AndroidHttpClient

Tags: java, android, http

I'm getting an `IOException` from my code using `AndroidHttpClient`. Is there something wrong with the code? The code is thrown whether I use `port 80` or `port 443`, and with Http Schema `http` or `https`.

The exception is thrown at `client.execute`...it is a `UnknownHostException` exception..I'm not sure why. I can hit the service from the browser.

```
        // declare locals
    JSONObject joResponse = new JSONObject();
    String response = "";

    try
    {
        // prepare to execute
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(hostname, Const.HTTP_PORT, Const.HTTP_SCHEME);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(null);

        // execute
        response = client.execute(target, get, responseHandler); // this is where the exception is thrown

        joResponse = new JSONObject(response);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: If you are getting an exception then it is best practice to show it along with the stack trace in your question.  It should be available from `adb -logcat`.

Comment: @Gray I have updated the question to include the exception. The `e.printStackTrace` throws a `Nullpointer`, because e = null.

Comment: `UnknownHostException` is an `IOException`.  So you put the `e.printStackTrace()` there and `e` was null?  That's not possible from a JVM standpoint.  If it was caught then it's not null.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the internet permission declared in your app?

You need to add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```